# Left aligned container on Chrome (Windows)

Tags: bug, design

Since several days, the container of ux stackexchange is left aligned :

[image]

After some inspections, I figured out that the property "overflow: auto;" on "#content" is causing this issue. I simply removed it and now it's all fine :

[image]

I'm using Chrome 34.0.1847.116 m on Windows 7. The issue seems not to appear on other browsers/os.

**EDIT : How to "fix" it**

If you are also having this issue, I'd suggest to use a plugin (stylebot on Chrome for example) and add this css line :

> #content { overflow: visible; }